# Convert Interface IDL file to C#

Tags: c#, interop, interface, idl

I have an interface defined in an IDL file that I would like to use in C#. Is there a way to convert the IDL to something usable in C#?

Comment: Something usable in C#. Something that will compile.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way is to run `MIDL` on the IDL to create a type library (.tlb). This requires a `library` block in the IDL. Once you have the .tlb, you can run `tlbimp.exe` on it to get a C# definition/Interop DLL.

Comment: and you then you can use [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to view the C# definition from the generated interop DLL.

Answer (score 6):

What datatypes/structures are used in the IDL? You should first define the datatypes in C# first if there is no inbuild type already.

You can use the following tool to convert the structures, but you need to verify the ouput manually.

Download: http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe

This utility is described at [Accessing Windows API Constants and Structs for P/Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122410/accessing-windows-api-constants-and-structs-for-p-invoke).

The original January 2008 article is now only available as a [.CHM help file download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJanuary2008en-us.chm), linked at the bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues. For the time being, the source code can be found at http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this>??

Comment: @ChandraEskay Since the link to the MSDN article was no longer correct, I took the liberty of updating the information about this utility.

Answer (score 2):

For example, I've recently used the XPS Print API and needed the xpsobjectmodel.h interfaces. The Windows SDK comes with xpsobjectmodel.idl fortunately.

I generated the TLB file with MIDL first and used TLBIMP to generate a proper DLL assembly ready to be added in the 'References...' section in my C# project.

Be sure to use the tools with the correct version for your project framework. e.g, if your project framework is 3.5-based, using tlbimp from the 4.0 toolset won't work.