# Accessing Windows API Constants and Structs for P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Quick question: How can I access the BN_CLICKED constant and other constants defined for the Win32 API from .NET? Are they defined in some library? Do I have to define them myself? If so, where can I find these values? And are the values version-specific between versions of Windows?

Comment: No source is perfect.  The web is infected with bad VB6 declarations, pinvoke.net is often ambiguous and misleading, pinvoke assistant is just ugly machine generated, the SDK requires master C skills.  Only one nearly perfect one: stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find the PInvoke Interop Assistant to be really helpful:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx.

It has almost everything and can convert the C++ to C#/VB for you. I rarely, if ever, resort to searching google/pinvoke.net anymore.
[image: Screenshot]

Here's the MSDN Magazine Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx

The original January 2008 MSDN Magazine Article is now only available as a [.CHM help file download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJanuary2008en-us.chm), linked from the very bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues. (Column "CLR Inside Out: Marshaling between managed and unmanaged code.")

And here's the download: http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe. The source code can be found at http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/.

Comment: This looks like a good tool to convert from the `.h` files (obtained using Uwe Keim's answer) to the C# P/Invoke signatures.

Comment: You usually don't need them.  Most of the constants and method signatures are included in its database.

Answer (score 6):

You could download the [Microsoft Platform SDK](http://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+platform+sdk+download) and take a look at the header files (`*.h`). E.g. the [`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx) is defined in the `winuser.h` file.

Usually, if you just need one or two constants, a [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=BN_CLICKED) and a look at the first few results is also sufficient, since the value is printed there.

Comment: For WM_COMMAND, that was useful and standard. But I've found two different values for BN_CLICKED with google.

Comment: @Legatou No rule without exception ;-) Platform SDK headers are definitely the best choose in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

http://pinvoke.net/ is an excellent resource for <strike>this</strike> *many common P/Invoke definitions*.

Comment: Really? I found that PInvoke.net is good for method signatures. I tried to find `BN_CLICKED` and did not succeed.

Comment: @Uwe Keim - You're right -- I assumed it was a typo for `BM_CLICK`, but it looks like `BN_CLICKED` does exist.  I couldn't find it on pinvoke.net either.

Answer (score 1):

The MagNumDB website (by SO user [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier)) is an easy way to look up constants:

http://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=BN_CLICKED

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a proof-of-concept, but I put together [a script](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/d8b744c994eaa59493648f8795d9dde8) that can look up most any Windows API constant. Example usage:

```
PS > .\Get-WindowsSDKConstant.ps1 BN_CLICKED
0
PS > .\Get-WindowsSDKConstant.ps1 BN_DBLCLK
5
PS > .\Get-WindowsSDKConstant.ps1 WM_COMMAND
273
```

It requires you to download [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) and the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), because behind-the-scenes it compiles a program that looks up the constant.

Finally, here's some answers to the asker's questions:

> Are [the constants] defined in some library?

The authoritative source is the [Windows Platform SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

> Do I have to define them myself?

They're not built-in to Windows or .NET, which means you'll probably define them yourself (or copy them from somewhere).

> And are the values version-specific between versions of Windows?

They're very stable, because otherwise a program compiled for one version of Windows might stop working when a user upgrades to a newer version of Windows. Microsoft goes to great lengths to prevent this from happening.

However, I've seen at least one place where the constants are different depending on what platform/architecture you're compiling on. I wouldn't assume that just because your code works on x86 64-bit Windows, it'll work on ARM 32-bit Windows RT, for example.