# Win API .NET library?

Tags: .net, winapi

I see `DllImport` everywhere. I see everybody declaring Win API methods in their projects. Why doesn't people put every Win API method declaration in a .NET library and use it instead?
Is there any such library? Is it open source?

Comment: Some of the Windows 7 APIs have made it into .NET 4, readily available to WPF developers.

Comment: I'm building a library like this as we speak...It's a long job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WindowsAPICodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) comes close for many things.

Comment: +1 Although specifically that's many of the new Windows 7/Vista features.

Answer (score 5):

Because this would be a *huge* library, and no one needs to call *all* of the Win API methods.

The closest thing that I know of is [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).

Many specific APIs have .NET wrappers, if you look around ([ESENT](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/), [IIS management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.aspx), [SQL management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx) and more).

Comment: See also the PInvoke Signature Generator tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122410/accessing-windows-api-constants-and-structs-for-p-invoke/5122534#5122534

Comment: NET is a huge library. I doubt it would increase much in size if it included those wrappers.