# Where to find example code for the RD Gateway API?

Tags: winapi, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I am trying to write a custom authentication module for the [Remote Desktop Gateway API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee672231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However there is no example code of how to use it on the MSDN. I also have been looking around on the net for any kind of tutorial for writing a custom authentication module, but have found none.

I have found a [few](http://networkdojo.net/2011/09/12/remote-desktop-services-rd-gateway/) [high level](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Configuring-Windows-Server-2008-Terminal-Services-Gateway-Part2.html) overviews of how RD Gateway works and how to set it up, and I can get the system as a whole working using Active Directory. However, I need to replace the AD login with a custom authentication module (the reason for the API), but I have not seen a single tutorial or working example code that implements the API.

Can anyone provide some working example code that uses the RD Gateway API? I have a strong feeling that I will not find any tutorials, but just seeing someone else's example code would help immensely.

Language does not matter, but as I have learned from my [other question about this API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468526/writing-com-servers-for-the-windows-api-in-c-where-to-begin) it would be better if the solution was native instead of managed, but a managed solution is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code can be found here -- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Desktop-Gateway-517d6273

Answer (score 2):

I ended up not going with the custom authentication module route, we just made a new domain and added users to that new domain instead.

The closest I ever found in the way of examples was [this MSDN archive](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/rdsdev) titled "Remote Desktop Services Developer Resources".

There is a document named "*[Using the Pluggable Authentication and Authorization (PAA) Framework for RD Gateway.docx](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/rdsdev/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3745)*" that has some information, but no example code. You can also check the "*[Resource Publishing and Connection Brokering](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/rdsdev/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3480)*" release and it does have some example code of the other RDS modules.