# MIDL not generating tlb

Tags: c#, c++, com, idl, midl

I'm trying to use COM interop, specifically with .net core and C++. I have a .net core library which I'm trying to expose to a C++ codebase.

The dotnet documentation mentions:

> Unlike in .NET Framework, there is no support in .NET Core or .NET 5+ for generating a COM Type Library (TLB) from a .NET assembly. The guidance is to either manually write an IDL file or a C/C++ header for the native declarations of the COM interfaces. If you decide to write an IDL file, you can compile it with the Visual C++ SDK's MIDL compiler to produce a TLB.

I tried creating my own IDL file that declared the interface I wanted to create:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[object, uuid(9526A66B-200B-4157-AEDC-56F084962031), pointer_default(unique)]
interface IMyInterface : IUnknown {
    HRESULT StartMethodA();
    HRESULT StartMethodB();
};
```

Which I'm compiling with `midl.exe test.idl` (I've also played around with extra `tlb` params). However, this compilation step only creates `.h` and `.c` files, but not a `.tlb`.

I've also looked into reverse pinvoke and also dllexport. In both cases (from my understanding) I was required to provide my c# as static methods. I could accomplish this by creating a static function which creates a new instance of the object whose member functions I need it to call. That does however feel like nasty workarounds.

I'm quite new to COM and writing a 'bridge' between C++ and .net core, hopefully someone can give me some pointers that would allow this to work.

**Resources**

[How do I expose a .netstandard2.0 library with COM for use in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540720/how-do-i-expose-a-netstandard2-0-library-with-com-for-use-in-vb6)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/com-dcom-and-type-libraries#type-library

https://mark-borg.github.io/blog/2017/interop/

[Calling C# code from C++, but ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain() is too limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778590/calling-c-sharp-code-from-c-but-executeindefaultappdomain-is-too-limited)

[What do you do when MIDL can't create a tlb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716579/what-do-you-do-when-midl-cant-create-a-tlb?rq=3)

**idl with library block**

I've also wrapper the interface with a `library` block, however, that did not result in a .tlb either (just like it's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269119/how-do-i-invoke-the-midl-compiler-to-generate-a-tlb-file-type-library-from-an)).

```
[
  uuid(123123V-200B-4157-AEDC-56F084962031),
  version(1.0)
]
library grpcLibrary {
  importlib("stdole2.tlb");
  [object, uuid(9526A66B-200B-4157-AEDC-56F084962031)]
  interface IKioskProcessor : IDispatch {
    HRESULT StartAutomaticProcess();
    HRESULT StartManualProcess();
  };
};
```

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\arm64> .\midl.exe C:\Users\kevin\grpc\GrpcLibrary.idl /tlb Foo.tlb
Microsoft (R) 32b/64b MIDL Compiler Version 8.01.0628
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
64 bit Processing C:\Users\kevin\grpc\GrpcLibrary.idl
GrpcLibrary.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\oaidl.idl
oaidl.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\objidl.idl
objidl.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\unknwn.idl
unknwn.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared\wtypes.idl
wtypes.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared\wtypesbase.idl
wtypesbase.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared\basetsd.h
basetsd.h
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared\guiddef.h
guiddef.h
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\ocidl.idl
ocidl.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\oleidl.idl
oleidl.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\servprov.idl
servprov.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\urlmon.idl
urlmon.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\msxml.idl
msxml.idl
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\oaidl.acf
oaidl.acf
64 bit Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um\ocidl.acf
ocidl.acf
```

Comment: There's no 'library' in your idl. The easiest to create and learn about tbls is to use OleView tool from Windows SDK (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/ole-com-object-viewer) and browse existing tlb (they can be .tlb files, or embedded in .dll, .ocx, etc.). For example oleview wshom.ocx will give you windows scripting host's one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your response. I've updated my post with the corresponding 'library' block, that still did not result in a .tlb file. I'll take a look at the links you've provided.

Comment: I fixed your uuid (it's not a good guid), ran `midl GrpcLibrary.idl` and got a GrpcLibrary.tlb.

Answer (score 0):

An IDL file with only interface declarations isn't going to generate a TLB, you need to declare a library containing the interfaces. It might also need coclass declarations as well, depending on your exact requirements.