# How can I generate The c# Files from IDL files?

Tags: c#, idl, geckofx

I am trying to Update the GeckoFX to work with Firefox 46 :
some classes in this folder :
"https://github.com/EbramTawfik/GeckoFX/tree/master/Geckofx-Core/Generated" have a different "uuid" guide Id
I have the IDL files in this folder "Which have the uuid":
https://github.com/EbramTawfik/GeckoFX/blob/master/PutXulRunnerFolderHere/firefox-46.0.win32.sdk.zip

Is there a way to regenerate the CS files from IDL files instead of updating the uuid manually?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Interface IDL file to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307675/convert-interface-idl-file-to-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, but How can I run MIDL? and is there a way to do it from Visual Studio ?

Comment: Visual Studio Command Prompt, you should be able to open it from VS and type `midl` command there.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs

Comment: If it's something you have to do frequently then you can also create some kind of script that executes `midl` for you and put it in some place like /scripts folder in your project directory

Comment: OK Thanks (Y) I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I Successfully did that :
This is the tool that should be used :
      https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/idlimp/src/default/

1- Build IDLImp project

2- Run IDLImp.exe with the file FullName as an argument

This is successfully done.